# Union can't be translated to SQL

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, .net-core-2.2

I'm using EFCore 2.2.3 and I have disabled local evaluation.

I have the following queries

```
var query1 = companyContext.Companies.Where(c => c.Name == name);
var query2 = companyContext.Companies.Where(c => c.Id == 10);
```

If i execute them on their own they work correctly.

```
await query1.ToListAsync();
await query2.ToListAsync();
```

But if i try to

```
var result = await query1.Union(query2).ToListAsync();
```

i get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The
>   LINQ expression 'Union({from Company c in
>   value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[MagliteTest.Database.Company])
>   where ([c].Id == 10) select [c]})' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by
>   passing event ID 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to
>   the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
>   'AddDbContext'.

Is union not supported on entity framework core?

Comment: If all you're doing is q1.Union(q2).ToListAsync( ), there's no harm in local evaluation. The problem for me is that I had `q1.Union(q2).Where(x => ...)` and the union part translated to a very expensive-to-execute query (many 10s of 1000s of rows, which the condition then filtered out).  In the end I had to do `q1.Where(x => ...).Union(q2.Where(x => ...))` after trying various solutions like `id in q1 OR id in q2` that I couldn't get to work.

Answer (score 6):

`Union` / `Concat` server (SQL) translation is not supported yet (as of EF Core 2.x).

The issue is tracked by [#6812 Query: Translate IQueryable.Concat/Union/Intersect/Except/etc. to server](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6812).

According to that link, it's scheduled for EF Core 3.0.

Comment: Thanks, guess i will have to enable local evaluation until 3.0 releases, seems lika huge downer.

Comment: Yeah. One of the greatest changes in 3.0 (can't wait for it!) actually will be the removal of client evaluation - [LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) :)

Comment: came across this link and amazed you suggested using client side evaluation. Would would you not use FromSql and still run it server side?

Comment: @Phil I'm not suggesting to use client evaluation. But in 2.x we have no options for these operators. In 3.0 it's supposed to translate and run server side. It already does that for supported LINQ query constructs, not sure what you mean by *not use `FromSql`*. Normally we don't need `FromSql`.

Comment: you can write raw SQL queries against your DbSet and have it return the object you require. Thats how i got around the current union limitation in 2.x. The comment was in reponse to @Peter who mentioned enabling local evaluation until 3.0 was released which is a massive no no!