# How to influence LINQ with EntityFramework Cores wrong Select decisions

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1.1 with EF Core 2.1.4.

In my application database I do have Parts and each Part has properties over a ClusterPart: e.g. References.

[image]

My cluster parts can have direct references like "**B -> C**" or two step references like "**A -> B -> C**".

I want to encapsulate this reference-logic into a service call which returns a IQueryable so that I can use this IQueryable to add even more information in multiple places.

The service to return the referenced ClusterParts as IQueryable. Don't spend too much time on the linq statements:

```
public IQueryable<ClusterPart> GetReferencedClusterParts(long partId)
{
    // Requested ClusterPart
    var requestedClusterPart = _clusterPartDao.GetClusterPartsByPartId(partId)
        .Include(cp => cp.Part)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Supplier)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.SupplierType)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    // Get direct references B to C
    var resultB2C = _clusterPartDao.GetAll() // This is just _context.Table
        .Where(cpB => cpB.PartId.Equals(requestedClusterPart.PartId)) // Requested PartId
        .SelectMany(cpB => cpB.ReferenceClusterPartIdFromNavigations) // Reference from A/B to C 
        .Select(rB2C => rB2C.ClusterPartIdToNavigation) // C ClusterPart
        .Where(cpC => cpC.Part.Supplier.SupplierTypeId.Equals(1)) // SupplierType C

    // Add 2 step references A to B to C
    var resultA2B2C = _clusterPartDao.GetAll() // This is just _context.Table
        .Where(cpA => cpA.PartId.Equals(requestedClusterPart.PartId)) // Requested PartId
        .SelectMany(cpA => cpA.ReferenceClusterPartIdFromNavigations) // Reference from A to B 
        .Select(rA2B => rA2B.ClusterPartIdToNavigation) // B ClusterPart
        .SelectMany(cpB => cpB.ReferenceClusterPartIdFromNavigations) // Reference from B to C
        .Select(rB2C => rB2C.ClusterPartIdToNavigation) // B ClusterPart
        .Where(cpC => cpC.Part.Supplier.SupplierTypeId.Equals(1)); // SupplierType C

    return resultA2B2C.Union(resultB2C);
}
```

Basically I just select the "C" ClusterParts referenced like **"B -> C**" and "**A -> B -> C**".

This method is used by:

```
var resultCP = GetReferencedClusterParts(12345)
    .Select(cpC => new ElementDTO
    {
        PartId = cpC.PartId,
        PartName = cpC.Part.Name
    });
result.References = resultCP.ToList();
```

As soon as I hit resultCP.ToList() the query(s) are fired.
It takes very long, as LINQ decides to select the full table "Part", which contains 10 million rows, event thou the call of "GetReferencedClusterParts" just returns ~10 results. I confiremd that in SQL Server Profiler.

When I remove "cpC.Part.Name", the Part table isn't fully selected.

How can I influence this situation? I want to avoid EF Core or LINQ to decide to select a whole big table instead of just joining that little information to the IQueryable which would be very quick, but I have no clue why the table "Part" is completely selected.

Comment: Might be related to [Union can't be translated to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494748/union-cant-be-translated-to-sql). I would suggest you turning [EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) on, especially [client evaluation logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation-logging) and see which expressions are reported as non translatable.

Comment: Thanks, I turned on the logging. Very helpful to find client evaluations, but it only tells you that its not working. Because internally EF-Core creates multiple queries, I thought, that I can do that by myself within C#, so after I union'ed, I used "ToList()" and joined the list to my ClusterPart-table again: "from cp in _clusterPartDao.GetAll() join l in list on l.Id==cp.Id select new ElementDTO {... PartName = cp.Part.Name..}". I thought I tricked EF-Core like that. But again I got a select to the FULL table. I'm going crazy here. :-(